# Infinite Scroll with table - React Virtualized

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I have been trying to implement Infinite scrolling with lists and table with `react-virtualized`.

I implemented an Infinite Scrolling which is very similar to this [example](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/InfiniteLoader/InfiniteLoader.example.js).

**loadMoreRows**

```
_loadMoreRows ({ startIndex, stopIndex }) {
    if(!completed){  //From redux store
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        loadData(() => resolve);
      });
    }
}
```

**rowRenderer**

```
 _rowRenderer ({ index, key, style }) {
    const row = list[index] //From store
    if(row) {
      content = row;
    } else {
      content = 'Loading'
    }
    return (
      <div
        className='row'
        key={key}
        style={style}
      >
        {content}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

And my List was

```
<List
  ref={registerChild}
  className='List'
  height={1000}
  onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
  rowCount={this.state.rowCount}
  rowHeight={100}
  rowRenderer={this._rowRenderer}
  width={width}
/>
```

inside

```
<InfiniteLoader
  isRowLoaded={this._isRowLoaded}
  loadMoreRows={this._loadMoreRows}
  rowCount={this.state.rowCount}
>
```

List worked like charm for me. I wanted to replace `List` component with the `Table`. So I replaced the list with following changes,

```
<Table
  ref={registerChild}
  width={300}
  height={300}
  headerHeight={20}
  rowHeight={30}
  rowCount={this.state.rowCount}
  rowRenderer={this._rowRenderer}
  rowGetter = {({ index }) => list[index]}
>

{Object.keys(headers).map((headerKey, index) => {
  return (
    <Column
        label={headers[headerKey].label}
        dataKey={headerKey}
        width={100}
        key={index}
    />
  );
})}
</Table>
```

The `list` from store is of format `[{'key': 'value'}]`. Infinite loader is not showing any error in console but the table is empty, filled with one `Loading` from rowRenderer.
Initially `this.state.rowCount` would be `1` and the `list` would be empty. Through `loadMoreRows` I was dispatching an action to fetch and populate `list`. After than I increased rowCount, which worked fine for `List` component. 
But since the list is empty at the first attempt, `loadMoreRows` was not triggered with `Table` component and is not working.

What could be the correct way to approach this?

Comment: `WindowScroller` and `Table` don't quite work correctly together. You might be better off writing your own fixed-header and then rendering rows with columns in them (within a `List`).

Comment: Great! I was expecting to do that if it is not possible to make it work with `Table`. Thanks.